# Problema con AutoPersistenceModel FluentNHibernate C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, wpf, orm, nhibernate

Tengo un problema con ***FluentNHibernate*** para poder usar ***Auto Persistence Model***, disculpen si no escribo adecuadamente las palabras técnicas.

Esta es la estructura de mi proyecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Siempre utilicé en la capa *data* todas la entidades de la base para que persistan y haga los ***CRUD***.

Este es el código que realiza la conexión.

```js
public class FluentySessionFactory
{
    private static ISessionFactory session;
    public static ISessionFactory CrearSession()
    {
        if (session != null)
            return session;
        else
        {
            AutoPersistenceModel model = CreateMappings();
            session = Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                .ConnectionString(c => c
                    .Server("SORA")
                    .Database("base_test")
                    .Username("aj")
                    .Password("Passw0rd")))
                .Mappings(m => m
                    .AutoMappings.Add(model))
                .BuildSessionFactory();
            return session;
        }
    }

    private static AutoPersistenceModel CreateMappings()
    {
        return AutoMap
            .Assembly(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly())
            .Where(t => t.Namespace == "Control.Acceso.Data.Entity.Entities");
    }
    public static ISession AbrirSession()
    {
        return CrearSession().OpenSession();
    }
}
```

Ahora, lo que quiero hacer, es poder separar de la capa *data* a una capa de `Entity` todas la entidades.

Creo la capa `Entity`, generó las mismas entidades, cambio el `Namespace` en el método `CreateMappings` pero cuando hace la consulta y quiere convertir a una entidad me tira un error que no puede persistir a esa `Entidad`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creo que esto es porque no está resolviendo la dirección donde están las entidades, porque si apunto a las entidades que están en la misma capa, las persiste sin problema.

Aclaración: Ya traté de resolver las entidades individuales con el `AutoMap.Assembly` y el `AutoMap.AssemblyOF`.

Update 01-03-2017
buenas noches. dejo el enlace de proyecto para que puedan darme una mano.

https://github.com/ajflores/Auto-Persistence-Model

Update 04-03-2017
Buenas noche. dejo un link de un video demostrardo la ejecucion del proyecto y el error.
https://youtu.be/F6ZN83y5m-M

**Update 11-03-2017**
Buenas. acabo de probar lo que me sugirió @CarlosCocom. Lamentablemente no funciono el código.
esto fue el resultado.

probando con la linea de codigo de @carlosCocom me tira esta exception
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no saliendo del método CrearSession.

agregando:

```html
var autoMap = AutoMap
            .Assembly(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Usuario))).Where(x=>x.GetType()==typeof(Usuario));
```

todavía no puede resolver la persistencia.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

probando de instan ciar un solo model:

```html
private static AutoPersistenceModel CreateMappings()
        {
             var autoMap = AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Usuario>()
                .Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(Usuario));
            return autoMap;
        }
```

sigo sin poder persister el model usuario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por el momento para salir del paso. estoy realizando consultas sql nativas obteniendo una lista de objetos y creando un usuario y asignando convirtiendo y asignando propiedad por propiedad. una negrada  :(

**Fin Update 11-03-2017**

esta desarrollada en .net c# interface wpf y wincastle. solo tiene una entity usuario para poder testear.

desde ya muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Alguien puede ayudarme con este problema?

Comment: no puedo ver las imágenes, pero me imagino que la capa entity es un proyecto class library, y ese proyecto lo agregas como referencia al proyecto de la capa de datos

Comment: En la ultima imagen donde dice el error, ve a la parte de abajo donde dice `acciones` y presiona el link `ver detalle...` y ahi proporciona mas información sobre el error si despliegas la lista

Comment: Hola Floajd. Para poder ayudarte, asegúrate de incluir un [mcve] para que podamos reproducir tu error.  Si logro reproducir tu error, veré si puedo encontrar una solución. Si no, con gusto le pondré una recompensa a tu pregunta para que reciba más atención. Pero lo primero es que incluyas un [mcve].

Comment: Hola @sstan muchas gracias por responde.
agregue el proyecto en github.  muchas gracias

Comment: como haces para ejecutar el codigo? la pantallita para ejecutar código? como la pones?

Comment: hola @OmarOmar, edite la pregunta agregando un vídeo de la ejecución de la solución. espero que puedas ayudarme. saludos.

Comment: @Floajd y como te fue con la [respuesta de Carlos](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/44321/problema-con-autopersistencemodel-fluentnhibernate-c#answer-54105).

Comment: Hola, @Davlio ahi agregue un update de la prueba que realice. lamentablemente sigo sin poder solucionar el problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu codigo

```
private static AutoPersistenceModel CreateMappings()
{
    return AutoMap
        .Assembly(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly())
        .Where(t => t.Namespace == "Control.Acceso.Data.Entity.Entities");
}
```

cambialo por

```
    private static AutoPersistenceModel CreateMappings()
    {
        var autoMap = AutoMap
            .Assembly(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Usuario)));

        return autoMap;
    }
```

Cargas el ensamblado incorrecto y el where nunca se cumple.
Entonces mejor carga el ensamblado donde esta definido tu entidad

Pues he bajado tu código y funciona sin problemas. Lo unico es que no me crea la bd pero la creado y despues le he dicho que hiciera un SchemaUpdate y en la conexion use

```
.Is("Server=(local);Database=Control_Activo;Trusted_Connection=True;")
```

[image: Screenshoot recuperando entidad]

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda @carlosCocom. hice un update con la prueba que realice. lamentablemente no tuve resultado.

Comment: tenes toda la razón funciona :). había modificado las entidades por eso no tomaba tu modificación. muchas gracias por el tiempo dedicado.

Answer (score -3):

Voy a tratar de reproducir tu código, pero una cosa que noté es que no es Thread Safe. Deberías tener algo como lo siguiente para que lo sea o poner un doble chequeo al hacer el singleton.

```
public class FluentySessionFactory
{
    private static readonly ISessionFactory session;
    static FluentySessionFactory()
    {
       AutoPersistenceModel model = CreateMappings();
            session = Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                .ConnectionString(c => c
                    .Server("SORA")
                    .Database("base_test")
                    .Username("aj")
                    .Password("Passw0rd")))
                .Mappings(m => m
                    .AutoMappings.Add(model))
                .BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    private static AutoPersistenceModel CreateMappings()
    {
        return AutoMap
            .Assembly(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly())
            .Where(t => t.Namespace == "Control.Acceso.Data.Entity.Entities");
    }
    public static ISession AbrirSession()
    {
        return CrearSession().OpenSession();
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Esto sería una recomendación o la respuesta a la pregunta? ¿Podrías explicar cómo resto resuelve al problema de la pregunta? De lo contrario, sería un comentario.